# Application "Preview" is not letting me mail a pdf

Tags: macos, preview

Why can't I share a pdf file from the Application Preview and mail it in Yosemite?

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the sharing icon in the toolbar should give you the option to mail the document.

[image]

Comment: that is a +1 from me for the funny name Musterfrau :)